# Group BY Date count how many

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have a sample table in **mysql** database as follows:

```
id       dateAdded
----------------------------
1        2013-12-24 03:03:19
2        2013-12-24 03:04:19
3        2013-12-24 03:06:14
4        2013-12-24 03:07:23
5        2013-12-25 03:04:19
6        2013-12-26 03:02:19
7        2013-12-26 03:03:19
```

I want to `COUNT` how many `ids` with the same `date` , so the result out will be :

```
date             Count
-----------------------
2013-12-24       4
2013-12-25       1
2013-12-26       2
```

Please if you could help me out with the **Mysql** query

Comment: `SELECT dateAdded,COUNT(dateAdded) FROM table GROUP BY dateAdded`

Comment: `SELECT dateAdded as date, COUNT(id) FROM table GROUP BY dateAdded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply grouping by DATE(dateAdded) should work well;

```
SELECT DATE(dateAdded) date, COUNT(*) Count
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc6d74/2).

Comment: I got only the first result       date             Count
-----------------------
2013-12-24       4

Comment: @user3150060 Are you sure? The SQLfiddle gets all of them, are you fetching all results?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `date()` or `date_format()` to put it in YYYY-MM-DD format first and then group by that:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
    ,date_format(dateAdded, '%Y-%m-%d') as dateAdded1
    // ,date(dateAdded) as dateAdded2
FROM
    TABLENAME
GROU BY
    dateAdded1 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dateAdded`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY date
```